# Multiple websites under a folder in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a problem with websites in IIS.

The first thing that I did was that I set basic `.html` website in IIS under `Default website (port 80)`. I moved the code in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test` and it works.

When I type in the browser `localhost/Test`, it works but I have an ASP.NET Core web app and I want to open it using `localhost/MyAspNetSite` in the browser. Is this possible???

I'm asking that because when I right click on the `Default website` I have no possibility to add new website, only virtual directory or application. In my case, I put my .net code in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\New` and in I added the new website on port 5000 and it works like `localhost:5000` but not like `localhost/New`. I hope that you understand me.

Is it possible to have two websites on the same port or to connect two websites or something like that?
I am sending image about this problem. Thank you

Comment: You can have multiple websites on IIS. Each node under "Sites", has its own URL. If you want to use myWebSite/Test, you will need to add an "Application" within your Site "myWebSite".

Comment: You can add more sites by right clicking Sites node in IIS Manager. There is no site under a site, as all sites should be at the same level.

Comment: Hmmm,I did it.. but my web app can't run..When I run localhost/Asp I get files of my app .Whyy?

Answer (score 1):

You can host multiple sites under the same IP Address. In this case, the IP Address is called "Shared IP Address". This concept is used by all the shared host providers in this world.

That you basically need to do is to go to your IIS -> click your domain -> Bindings -> and add "www.yourDomain.com" and "YourDomain.com" to the IP. If you have a second site, you just have to do exactly the same thing, you can check this blog post it can help u to understand all that things

http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/